# How to convert varchar to date for existing table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to convert varchar value to date from my existing mysql table. I have tried many code for converting these datatype but I am unable to convert. I have given below using my code and shared screen shot. So please kindly help to me to resolve this issue.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20151001')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select
    date_format(DATE_ADD(from_unixtime(0), interval '1433169856' second), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as my_new_date;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Great It's working fine now.Thanks lot